# I cannot see my whole substance painter in any window

Tags: substance-engine

I cant really say anything else about it, every time I launch the program now, regardless of how, my windows show up like so: [image: can only see the top left corner of any window related to the program, can interact with the white zones though]

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an issue with your graphic card/cards. Try disabling the motherboard one if you have a gaming laptop and see if that helps.

Comment: what is a motherboard one? a little confused on what you mean, but yes I was moving from my school's computer to my personal laptop so that would be the situation

Comment: On your laptop you probably only have one graphics card. This is supposing that you were on a desktop computer where there was a built-in display card component on the motherboard and a separate more powerful one plugged into an expansion slot.

Comment: If you have a gaming laptop, there is always two graphics card. One on the motherboard, ex Intel Iris, and then a dedicated graphics card, ex Nvidia RTX 3060. If you disable the one on the motherboard, your HDMI port won't work if you don't use a dongle on a USB-C with a Thunderbolt connection that is connected to the dedicated graphics card instead of the integrated one, and things like Blender doesn't work at all. So I assume it could have something with that to do. But was mostly a wild guess.